# jQuery: How to enable button when only all check boxes are clicked?

Tags: jquery

How to enable the "button" when all check boxes are clicked?

For example:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="button1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="button2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="button3" />

  <input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    // on change event
    var bool;
    $("input.checkbox").change(function() {
        bool = $(".checkbox:not(:checked)").length !=0;
    // enable/disable
       $("#submitbutton").prop('disabled', bool);
    })
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/J3Pmy/2/)**

Comment: Why do you need the conditional expression? `!=` already returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a checkbox is clicked, set the `disabled` property if there are any unchecked boxes.

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    $("#submitbutton").prop('disabled', $(".checkbox:not(:checked)").length != 0);
})
```

Comment: it might be wiser to listen to change event instead of click.

Comment: I don't think it makes much difference. Clicking on a checkbox always changes it.

Comment: what i meant was that you can check a checkbox with keyboard without clicking it.

Comment: OK, I changed it. But I just tried it in Chrome, and checking a box with the keyboard triggered the `click` event.

Comment: See this: [SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35)

Comment: thanks for making me realize this, looks like it's not a problem anymore. firefox fired the event too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
//grab the set of check-boxes just one time:
var $checkboxes = $('form [type="checkbox"]');

//on each click, look at them, if there are no unchecked boxes, un-disalbe the submit:
$checkboxes.on('change', function(){
    if(!$checkboxes.filter('not:([checked])').length){
        $('submitbutton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make your current code a little more general for this to work.
Check for every checkbox being checked when any one is clicked.

See [this adaptation of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/UH6Ur/3/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '[type="checkbox"]' ).click(function() {
        if( allChecked() ){
           $("#submitbutton").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        }
        else{
            $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}); 

function allChecked(){
    var checkboxes = $( '[type="checkbox"]' ),
        allChecked = true;

    checkboxes.each( function( i, e ){
        allChecked = allChecked && $(e).is( ":checked" );
    });

    return allChecked;
}
```