# jQuery: How to enable button when all check boxes are clicked? - PART2

Tags: jquery, html

First, I will thank all who helped me with the first example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442608/jquery-how-to-enable-button-when-only-all-check-boxes-are-clicked/22442757?noredirect=1#22442757)

How will it work when I have something like this with multiple fieldsets:

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Option 1</legend>
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="1"  />1<br />
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="1" />2<br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Option 2</legend>
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="2" />1<br />
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="2" />2<br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Option 3</legend>
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="3" />1<br />
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="3" />2<br />
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Yr2/) here. I will thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
$('form input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var total = $('form fieldset').length;
    $('#submitbutton').prop('disabled', ($('input:checked').length === total) ? false : true)
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m4Yr2/2/)**